# How can I vertically center my image in this div?

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I am using the following code in my header to display my logo and my navigation. I vertically centered my text with `line-height: 90px;` but when I try to give my logo `vertical-align: middle;` it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

```css
header {
  max-width: 960px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 90px;
  background: #444444;
}
header img {
  width: 59px;
  height: 32px;
  float: left;
}
nav {
  float: right;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav li:not(:last-child) {
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
  <!-- Bild fehlt noch - SVG -->

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Start</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About me</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Comment: hey can you make one fiddle for same ?

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
header {
  max-width: 960px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 90px;
  background: #444444;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
header img {
  width: 59px;
  height: 32px;
}
nav {} nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav li:not(:last-child) {
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
}
nav ul li a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/59/32" alt="Logo">
  <!-- Bild fehlt noch - SVG -->

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Start</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About me</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the same but now it seems to work :)